# How to apply clause on right table in JPA left join

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables i.e. User and UserWallet now i want to create query in JPA in respect to sql query :-

```
working SQL query:-
SELECT * FROM user u left join user_wallet uw on u.id=uw.user_id and uw.wallet_type=2 where u.id = 2;
```

JPA query:-

```
not working:-
select w.address as walletAddress,u.id as id from User u left join u.userWallets w  w.walletType=2 where u.id=:id
```

Comment: You mean, by adding an ON clause in JPQL, like is supported in JPQL since JPA 2.1?

Comment: yes, it's solved , i updated jpa version to 2.1 and works fine now thanks @BillyFrost